# Upon inserting pdf file not image is seen in final document

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include

Good morning. I am trying to insert a pdf file: mga.pdf into a doc and upon compiling I get a blank doc sans pdf file. Not sure what to do here. As I said it compiles fine but I do not see the pdf image there at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

-MD

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm,  top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\date{}
\title{PHILIP DYKES}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\includegraphics{mga}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just for fun, is it on page 2? Includepdf are for inserting full pdf pages, not limited images, use includegraphics for that. Additionally includepdf issues a newpage before start, and since you use maketitle, that newpage is used and the images go to page 2

Comment: 1 page only. I just edited my post to reflect changes I tried but now I get: "file mga not found"? Despite the fact that the tex file & mga.pdf are in the same folder. -MD

Comment: While, testing, also have a look at those margins. width looks wrong. Can we have the exact log? Editors are not always that good at parsing the log. Also are 100% sure the spelling is correct? Are you on a system where case matters in file names? Exactly which engine are you using to compile?

Comment: No issues with the code here

Comment: @daleif: File `mga' not found. \includegraphics{mga} I am on ubuntu 17.04, and using texstudio 2.11.2

Comment: What does `ls -l mga.pdf` give you from a terminal and switched to that exact folder? How exactly did you get LaTeX on this compulter and have you been messing with the settings for LaTeX? (for example such that it does not look in the current directory for files)

Comment: I get: -rw-rw-r-- 1 rihanna rihanna 23362 Aug 10 08:52 mga.pdf
I got tex via texlive over the internet. And, I do not think so.

Comment: Over the internet means different things. Through Ubuntu or manually through TUG.org? They are not always the same. What happens if you compile the tex file manually in a terminal? `pdflatex file.tex`. Can we see the exact log from when you compiled the above exact MWE.

Comment: Hmmm now when compiling from a terminal it compiles fine (though the image is off-center - shifted to the right a few inches). And I installed tex initially through  ubuntu then texlive 2017 through tug. Why was texstudio giving me problems and how can I adjust the image to center please?

Comment: You have not told it to center the image. That should be in any introduction to latex. If you are completely new, have a look at  http://www.dickimaw-books.com/people/nicola-talbot.html

Comment: My guess is that terminal grabs one LaTeX installation, your editor grabs the other. Compile in the terminal, look in the `.log` file afterwards. Where does it say `article.cls` is located. Then compile from your editor, again, look in this new `.log` and see where `article.cls` is located in the file system.

Comment: My guess is that when TUG TeXLive asked you to add the TeXLive path to your path you did so in `.bashrc` or similar and when you start your editor you do so from a menu or by double clicking on a `.tex` file. This is a **very** common error on Linux. `.bashrc` only affects (bash) shells. The shell the editor uses to run LaTeX never uses `.bashrc` and thus that PATH change never happens.